# How can I disable "All exceptions" in XCTestCase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest

I usually have "All exceptions" ON in my Xcode Project.

This is one unit test in XCTestCase

```
- (void)testInitNotAllowed
{
    XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed([[PON_GameStatistics alloc] init], NSException, @"Singleton");
    XCTAssertNoThrowSpecificNamed([[PON_GameStatistics alloc] init], NSException, @"Singleton1");
}
```

First line is testing if exception is throw and I am expecting that it will be thrown.
So every time when I run this unit test, what mean every time when I run all unit test per project or per this file. Unit test stop because I have "All exceptions" ON.

So what I end up doing is following.
Set "All exceptions" OFF when running unit test and there setting it back ON when I am coding or doing manual test on simulator.

**Question**
Is there way to have "All exceptions" ON but somehow to tell Xcode not to stop on "All exceptions" ON inside this test case ?

This would save me lot of time.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've gotten in the habit of turning it off whenever I run my unit tests.

Comment: For me, an ideal solution would be to have the breakpoint exception still work for _unexpected_ exceptions. But that's probably asking for too much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can do that with conditional breakpoints.

1. Add a new breakpoint at the beginning of the snippet.
2. Introspect it and choose *Debugger Command* for *Action*.
3. Enter the debugger command:

   breakpoint disable
4. Check *Autmatically continue* …

This will automatically turn breakpoints off. Of course you can turn them on after the snippet.

Comment: If I remember correctly, tests are run in alphabetical order. Could you add a new test class that started with a bunch of a's in which you turn off breakpoints and then in the last test turn them back on?

Comment: @Amin this is some work around, is it possible to do this with some `#pragma mark` ? It is easier to do it in code and to see it. I will way day or so for accepting answer.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I think, that this behavior is neither guaranteed nor documented. Why should one do this, if one can turn off the breakpoints inside the method? (Everywhere where you can set a breakpoint.)

Comment: @WebOrCode I do not think so, because #pragma addresses the compile time, while debugging addresses the runtime.

Comment: @Amin If one has inherited a project with dozens of existing unit tests that throw exceptions, one would want a solution that doesn't need to be applied to each test individually.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Intentionally throws exceptions. Something that should happen rarely using Objective-C …

Comment: @Amin This is not a hypothetical. I've inherited multiple iOS projects which had unit tests that expected exceptions to be thrown. Whether or not these unit tests _should_ have been written in the first place is not the question.